# Postfix using asterisk user to send emails. Mapping did not work, are there any other options?

Tags: postfix, asterisk

I am trying to set up a PBX server to send voicemails to emails, which is being triggered properly, however, the from email is not the correct one I want to use. Instead of using support@mydomain.com, it's using asterisk@sip.domain.co.uk

So far I have tried adding mappings into generic file for postfix:

```
root@*   support@mydomain.com
asterisk@*   support@mydomain.com
```

Then making sure it's being relayed to properly

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

But that did not do anything

I've tried changing this setting in main.conf file:

```
#myorigin = $myhostname
#myorigin = $mydomain
```

But it just overwrites the domain part and the asterisk@... still remains.
I have reloaded postfix multiple times, as well as wrote the mappings into .db file after updating them.

I'm simply not sure what to try anymore, I've tried to apply any fix I've found online and I am writing here as last resort